# Ubuntu server strange locale issue

Tags: server, 13.10, apt, locale, perl

Installed brand new Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit on Hetzner server. Right after install tried to execute apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade. Getting following error nearly on all apt-get operation

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Googled a lot and tried a lot of solutions. No success. Still same warnings. Very annoying and don't know what's stand behind.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `/etc/default/locale` file incorrectly includes the line

```
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
```

If so, just remove that line. (There is no "UTF-8" locale name.)